# why does the pin it button create an iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

The display logic of the pin it button lies outside the iframe but still an iframe is created.
It could be that the iframe is created so as to not interfere with the parent pages style but are there any references on the same?. Thanks.

Comment: I think he's referring to the Pinterest button...

Answer (score 1):

Iframes are created to also take advantage of cookies that contain auth tokens for seemless interaction, like the follow me twitter button or the facebook like button.

Comment: Interesting. @mike, Would an iframe with no src work for such usage?. I mean a dummy iframe.

Comment: or does it have to load another page with cookies set?.

Comment: it has to load another page, it is a separate web container or view.  If you point it to an internal link you have full access to the iframe when it is pointed to google, facebook or pinterest, it is essentially  the same as go to that url in your main browser window.  And thus you cannot style a page that exists on another site, at least through the dom security sandbox directly.